# "DNS lookup failed" constantly

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8, google-chrome, dns

I just recently bought a new laptop, and for the first week or so it worked fine. Recently though, I've been having issues getting on the Internet.

Most of the time, when I attempt to open Google Chrome, or certain online games, the game won't load, and Google Chrome gives me an error message saying that "DNS lookup failed". I've tried everything I can imagine to fix it, but nothing works. Every once in a while, it will randomly start working, but it soon stops working again.

I'd like to note that it's only some things that don't work too. Skype and Internet Explorer work usually (though there have been some instances where they have not), but other browsers and applications won't connect to the Internet, even when it says I have Internet access.

Can anyone assist me with fixing this?

Comment: What are your DNS settings? When IE and skype work do they still work if you flush the DNS cache?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by settings, I'm assuming you're referring to the Preferred/Alternate DNS server. Mine is set as Preferred: 208.67.222.222, With nothing in the Alternate section. When I had it set to "Obtain DNS server address automatically", it would hardly ever work.

Comment: And yes, IE and Skype still work after flushing the DNS cache

Answer (score 0):

You can set up 8.8.8.8 as your primary DNS server in the network settings. It is Google public DNS server it will work if you have internet